# Как исправить ошибку MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

Вот код, который должен удалять запись после запроса.

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   port=3306,
   user="root",
   database = 'diss',# название БД
   password="")# Если пароль есть, то нужно указывать   
cur = cnx.cursor(buffered=True) 
cur.execute("select owner from shop ORDER BY RAND()") #Вместо price пишите столбец который вам нужен
result = cur.fetchone()
for x in result:
    print(x); 
    cur.execute('delete from shop where owner = %s', (result[0]))
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close() 
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813) 
    await channel.send(f'Ваш код:{ result[0]}',)
```

И следующая ошибка:

> Could not process parameters: str(2), it must be of type list, tuple or dict.

Не могу найти такой данный тип данных.

Comment: На какой строке данная ошибка?

Comment: @4500zenja     cur.execute("select owner from shop ORDER BY RAND()") , вроде на этой

Comment: `(result[0])` исправьте на `(result[0],)`

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо! Все работает!!